# swagger-node only to serve API Docs

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

Is there a way to install and start only "reduced" Swagger-node configuration, being able only to serve API specs?

I am not using swagger-node web server, as I have my own.

I would just use swagger-node to visualize nicely the APIs.

**UPDATE:**
I installed the swagger-ui as explained here: http://idratherbewriting.com/pubapis_swagger/#b-set-up-the-swagger-ui

Unfortunatelly, I cannot change the URL to point to my own file. If I follow the instructions, copy ma YAML in "dist" folder and change the URL to "my.yml" and open index.html in the browser, it tries to fetch "...index.html/my.yml".
How to fix this?

Comment: you need swagger UI tool or some other tool competitive to swagger ?

Comment: swagger ui is ok, but I'm not sure how to use it optimally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your swagger lerning from : http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/

You can create documentation, API authentication, models etc.

It will create a JSON and you can test your json for UI and functionality over here. http://petstore.swagger.io/

You can download this template and can upload on your domain. its an HTML template so can easily upload on any hosting.